# Telescopic groups

Tags: group-theory

Let's say that a group $G$ is "telescopic" if for all non negative integer $n$, $Aut^{(n+1)}(G)$ is a subgroup of $Aut^{(n)}(G)$. Clearly the trivial group and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ are telescopic. Are there any others?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "is a subgroup of"? Perhaps "is ***isomorphic*** to a subgroup of"?

Comment: yes, "is isomorphic to a subgroup of". I consider 2 isomorphic groups as the same group.

Comment: Can you define what $\operatorname{Aut}^{(n)}$ is?

Comment: @Sylvain: To be honest, that is a really terrible way of thinking about things. At a minimum I recommend asking a separate question on the subject of why you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Ian Coley: $Aut^{(0)}(G):=G$, $Aut^{(n+1)}(G):=Aut(Aut^{(n)}(G))$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$ should work. One seems to quickly run into trouble looking for more complicated finitely-generated abelian groups, though.

Comment: How about any group $G$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \cong G$?

Comment: It may or may not be of comfort to know that *every* group has an iterated automorphism group of the form Mikko Korhonen mentions, as long as we permit transfinite iteration. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808094v1

Comment: Ok, let's say that a group $G$ such that $Aut(G)\cong G$ is "automorphically self-similar" and that a group $H$ is "strictly telescopic" if it is telescopic and not automorphically self-similar. I'm essentially interested in strictly telescopic groups.

Comment: @ZevChonoles In case Sylvain does not ask that question as you recommend, do you think you could briefly explain why you think it is a terrible way of thinking about things?  I think I have always thought in the same way, for example, I know I've used the phrase "Consider the $V_4$ in $A_4$", or "look at $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Ryan: I think the point is that in the subgroup lattice of a group there may be many different `copies' of a group, so you have to think of them as being different subgroups since they are! There are also logical problems in thinking of a group as an isomorphism calss of groups, as then what does an automorphism of that group give. This, of course, can be avoided but that can get very confusing. You may or may not like a categorical viewpoint but taking a more categorical view does get around this and makes the overall structure more transparent.

Comment: @TimPorter: Thanks for the explanation!  I see there are a lot of problems I never thought of.